# Create specific array from text Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a text that is **String**, with a lot of words, but I need to create from it a specific array that will consist of all words that start with **capital** "A" and should not have "\n". Words with capital "A" do not repeat.

I am struggling with deleting " \ " and how to work with capital letters.

Comment: Did you already write some code to accomplish this? If yes, please edit your question and add it in so we can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let captialAs = string
    .split(whereSeparator: { $0 == "\n" || $0 == " " })
    .filter { $0.starts(with: "A") }
```